# Can't save configuration of NETunnelProviderManager

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-app-extension, tunnel, networkextension

I'm getting error:

`Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=5 "permission denied"`

when I try to save configuration on NETunnelProviderManager. This is my code:

```
NETunnelProviderManager * man = [[NETunnelProviderManager alloc] init];
NETunnelProviderProtocol *protocol = [[NETunnelProviderProtocol alloc] init];

[protocol setServerAddress:@"aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"]; // not actual value
[protocol setUsername:@"testuser"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:@"UUID" forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
[dictionary setObject:data forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessible];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(id)kSecClass];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];

CFTypeRef passwordRef = nil;

OSStatus delStatus = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary);
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, &passwordRef);

[protocol setPasswordReference:(__bridge NSData * _Nullable)(passwordRef)];

man.protocolConfiguration = protocol;
man.localizedDescription = @"My VPN";
man.onDemandEnabled = NO;
man.enabled = YES;

[man saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *err) {
    NSLog(@"saved preferences: error = %@", err);
}];
```

I have Personal VPN enabled in Capabilities and have .entitlements files in both app and network extension.

Comment: Check if your provisioning profile has all the appropriate entitlements.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your app is not capable (doesn't have permission) for reading or writing the Network Extension preferences.

Check on developer.apple.com at your app's ID that it uses Network Extensions and Personal VPN. In your Xcode project target don't use automatic provisioning profile handling. Instead make them manually at Provisioning Profiles section. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Xcode -> Project -> Targets -> Capabilities** and
Enable VPN and Enable Network Extensions.[image]